# How can I hide the filters part of a power bi report?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have a asp.net 4.5 web application that I use Power BI Embedded to show my reports developed and uploaded to PowerBI. This part works well.

However, I want to hide the "Filters" section on the right from my power bi reports.

[image]

In the picture above, I can see the CSS code of the part. There is no ID that I can use to reach from my .aspx class. I am trying to override the css but whatever I tried it would not work. Setting `?&filterPanelEnabled=False` at the end of my URL also did not work.

How can I hide the filters part of a power bi report? ANy help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! All we need to do is to add filterPaneEnabled: false as a setting to the javascript part like below:

```
<script src="../Scripts/powerbi.js" />

<script>
   var config = {...
                 settings: {filterPaneEnabled: false}
                 ...
                };
</script>
```